# Integrar C e C++

Tags: c, c++

Bom dia pessoal.

Tenho um programa principal em C, e quero apenas chamar uma função que está em outro arquivo C++ e obter o retorno desta função.

Como faço isso? 
Pesquisei e vi que "extern" pode ajudar mas não estou conseguindo sucesso.

Segue o que quero fazer:
No programa.c:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include "chain_code.cpp" // Arquivo C++ 
extern int chains(char*); 

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){ 

      // Faz alguma coisa 

     printf("%d ", chains(argv[1])); // Chama a função que está programada em C++

}
```

No arquivo "chaincode.cpp":

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp" 
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp" 
// Outros includes 


int chains(char* path){ 

// Gera histograma da imagem Path 
// devolve a media do histograma
```

Sou novo aqui então desculpe se dificultei um pouco a leitura

Comment: Não é aconselhável chamar código C++ a partir de C. O compilador de C++ faz *"name mangling"* o que torna as funções escondidas para o C. O C++ tem excepções na sua biblioteca interna e o compilador de C não sabe lidar com isso, É mais fácil usar o C tendo como base o C++.

Comment: Hmm.. e como eu faria isso?

Comment: "e como eu faria isso?" Escreve o programa principal em C++. Todos os problemas de mistura de linguagem deixam de existir :-)

Comment: Se sua rotina não é uma classe, bastas colocar a declaração exatamente como ela é escrita. O Fonte deve estar no projeto e não como um include. O compilador se encarrega de localizar a rotina.

Comment: Acontece que tem outras funções já desenvolvidas em C, e isso não sera possível

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível compilar um código **C++** em **C**, mas é possível compilar um código **C** em **C++**.

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int sum(int x, int y);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    printf("O código da: %d\n", sum(15,5));

    return 0;
}
```

sum.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" int sum(int x, int y){
    cout << (x+y) << endl;
    return x+y;
}
```

É necessário fazer a compilação em partes.

```
gcc main.c -o main.o -c
g++ sum.cpp -o sum.so -c
g++ main.o sum.o -o programa.exe
```

Com isso, tudo é integrado nas funcionalidades do **C++**.

O jeito mais viável de se fazer isso é usando bibliotecas dinâmicas.

```
g++ -fPIC -shared sum.cpp -o sum.so # sum.dll caso esteja no windows
gcc main.c ./sum.so # sum.dll caso esteja no windows
```

Esse método divide seu código deixando uma parte em **C** e outra em **C++**.

> **Obs: Se for integrar C com C++, faça seu trabalho todo em C++, isso é algo que não vale a pena ficar misturando.**